# Integration between MS Outlook and MySQL

Tags: mysql, vba, outlook, mysql-workbench

is there any way to connect/Integrate MS Outlook folders to MYSQL **single table** including Outlook inbox, sent items and if any other folders created by users.

**Single Table** Format:

|Id|Folder Path|Subject|DisplayTo|DisplayCc|DateTimeSent|DateTimeReceived|IsRead|HasAttachments|Preview|

Below are requirements:

1. Configure MS Outlook with MySQL
2. New incoming mail comes to inbox it should get triggered to MySQL table with above format
3. whenever outgoing mail goes to it should get triggered to MySQL table with above format
4. connection should check every 60 seconds/ possible intervals

These are tools involved with this project MS Access as front end application, MYSQL as Database and MS outlook as data source.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to develop an add-in for Outlook to have a corresponding MySQL db filled with Outlook data. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019) for more information.

There are two core events you need to handle to cover incoming and outgoing emails:

- The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.
- The `ItemSend` event is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an `Inspector` (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the `Send` button) or when the `Send` method for an Outlook item, such as `MailItem`, is used in a program.

Comment: sorry for delayed response but Actually I am new to Outlook VBA and on top of this VSTO :). would you please guide/give me more information.

Comment: I've provided the link to the walkthrough which provides exact steps for creating a VSTO based add-in

Comment: Sure I will go through link and try connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Something like you can create VSTO add-ins using visual studio and code will be something like below

```
     Outlook.Application application;
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        application = this.Application;
        application.NewMailEx += Application_NewMailEx;
        application.ItemSend += Application_ItemSend;            
    }

    private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
       if(Item is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            //extract all property and save
        }
    }

    private void Application_NewMailEx(string EntryIDCollection)
    {
       var item= application.Session.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection);
        if(item is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            // extract mailitem property and save to database
        }
    }
```

If you want to develop a paid version, you can contact me in Upwork.
[https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/~01b266b20bfa60411d](https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/%7E01b266b20bfa60411d)

For free help , post comment here :)